# progress of a format?

Tags: windows-7, formatting

I'm doing a low level format of a 4.63GB partition via Computer Management -> Disk Management (ie. i unchecked the quick format checkbox) and am not seeing a percentage completed thing anywhere indicating the progress.

Has Windows 7 just decided that they're too good for progress indicators or something?

Comment: screenshots? more information? NTFS? is it a removable drive?

Answer (score 9):

The word "Formatting" appears with no numeral and the percent sign only prior to the completion of the first percentage amount. So it will, if you let it, show 1% but only after that point has been reached. This took some time in my case (the reason I searched for this discussion) because it is a 3 terabyte external hard disk drive.

Answer (score 4):

cmd utility diskpart has a format option that will show you format progress in percentage.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx